# Image preview short path vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Im using the extension [image preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kisstkondoros.vscode-gutter-preview) to show a preview of the image when you move the mouse on it.

Would like to ask if there's something in vscode to consider a string as a path.

I mean I type `foo\o_7174.png` and vscode **consider** (NOT replace) it as
`C:\Users\CAIO\Documents\Github\images\o_7174.png`

I tried to add the `images folder` to the workspace and type `o_7174.png` but the extension did not find the image, it only finds the image if I type the full path or add the image to the same folder of the script.

[image]

Comment: you have the source code so you can modify the extension, why would a relative path be extended with `C:\Users\CAIO\Documents\Github\images`? Where is the `foo` part in the full path

Comment: @rioV8 how im suppose to edit this? https://i.imgur.com/C9D2lZY.png, you can ignore the `foo` thing, my question is how to load the images from a folder different than where is the script, using just the image name i.e `x.png`

Comment: https://github.com/kisstkondoros/gutter-preview/blob/master/src/extension.ts looks readable to me

Comment: since when does HTML image URI's use Windows path separators

Comment: `my question is how to load the images from a folder different than where is the script, using just the image name i.e x.png`

Comment: that will never happen if you don't mention where to look in the settings of the extension, if the extension does not have such a setting.......

Comment: the extension doesnt not have this setting

Comment: then modify the extension so it has such a setting and use it

Comment: if i know how to modify it i wasn't here asking

Comment: you program in JavaScript and the extension is written in JavaScript so what is the problem

Comment: create an issue with this extension